# Is the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(m, n) = 2 + m + n^2$ onto?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I took a quiz and got $50\%$ off a given question, I was wondering what I did wrong.

Q: Determine whether the function $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is onto if $f(m,n) = 2 + m + n^2$.

I wrote that is is not onto due to the $n^2$ making it a parabola and those are not onto functions.

Comment: Work directly from the definition of onto.

Answer (score 4):

You overlooked the fact that $f$ is a function of **two** variables. Let $k$ be any integer; then

$$f(k-2,0)=(k-2)+2+0^2=k\;,$$

so $k$ is in the range of $f$. Thus, $f$ does map $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ onto $\Bbb Z$. In fact, we don’t even need all of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$: the calculation above shows that $f$ maps $\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$ onto $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Hi Brian, quick question: is it correct to interpret the sentence “$y$ is a function of $x$” as “there exists a function $f$ such that $y=f(x)$”? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Yes, I would interpret those to be synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

The function is onto for fixed $n$. It is thus clearly onto if we let $n$ vary.

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote that is is not onto due to the n2n2 making it a parabola and those are not onto functions.

You need to work directly from the definition of onto. You did not do this. It's more like you guessed and are now coming here for the correct proof.

Hint: work directly from the definition of onto. A function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is onto if for every $b \in B$ there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. Please proceed from there. In this case $A = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, so an $a \in A$ would actually be a $(x,y) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. In particular, *both* $x$ and $y$ are free. Now proceed...